# Esconder selector hasta que coincida el valor

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

Buenas tengo tres selects dependientes, pero puedo esconder los dos ultimos hasta que seleccione el primero?? Hay que decir que el segundo es funcional cuando del primero recibe el valor 263

```
         <!-- Este es el primero -->
          <h3 style="margin-top: 8%;">Población</h3>
              <div class="ui form">
                <div class="field">
                  <select id="poblacion" class="ui search dropdown">
                    <option value="">Todos</option>
                    <?php
                    $results = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM poblacion");
                    foreach ($results as $pobl){
                    ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $pobl['poblacion_id'] ?>"><?php echo $pobl['poblacion'] ?></option>
                   <?php } ?>
                  </select>
                  </select>
                </div>
              </div>

             <!-- Este es el segundo -->

              <h3 style="margin-top: 8%;">Zona</h3>
              <div class="ui form">
                <div class="field">
                  <select id="distrito" class="ui search dropdown">
                    <option value="">Todos</option>
                    <?php
                    $results = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM distrito");
                    foreach ($results as $dis){
                    ?>
                   <?php } ?>
                  </select>
                </div>
              </div>

             <!-- Este es el tercero -->

              <h3 style="margin-top: 8%;">Barrio</h3>
              <div class="ui form separaSelect">
                <div class="field">
                  <select id="barrio" class="ui search dropdown">
                    <option value="">Todos</option>
                    <?php
                    $results = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM barrio");
                    foreach ($results as $bar){
                    ?>
                   <?php } ?>
                  </select>
                </div>
              </div>
```

Comment: lo que deseas es con javacript asi que recomiendo coloques solo el codigo html generado por php no el php como tal.

Answer (score 0):

Te dejo un ejemplo de como lo haria, creo que se aproxima al resultado que queres lograr:

```js
let select1 = document.querySelector('#primero');
let select2 = document.querySelector('#segundo');
let select3 = document.querySelector('#tercero');

select1.addEventListener('change' ,(e)=> {
   if(e.target.value == 2){
     select2.disabled = false;
   }
});

select2.addEventListener('change' ,(e)=> {
   if(e.target.value == 2){
     select3.disabled = false;
   }
});
```

```html
<select id="primero">
   <option value="1">Seleccione una opcion</option>
  <option value="2">Hola</option>
</select>
<select  id="segundo" disabled>
   <option value="1">Seleccione una opcion</option>
  <option value="2">Mundo</option>
</select>
<select id="tercero" disabled>
   <option value="1">Seleccione una opcion</option>
  <option value="2">!</option>
</select>
```